# Using the value of trackbar as a variable for another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, trackbar

I want to use a trackbar for a game that I'm working on using Winforms in VS2013.

The idea is that the user should choose on how fast a ball goes using a trackbar (use the value from the track bar for another variable in a different class).

Here's the code I currently have:

```
public static int trackBarValue;
//... Other global variables

public Form1()
{
    //... Other code
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    trackBarValue = trackBar1.Value;
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ball.moveBall();
}
```

And in my ball class, where I want the values of the trackbar to be used:

```
// Declaring the variables for Ball Speed in X and Y coordinates
private int xSpeed, ySpeed;

public Ball()
{ 
    //... Other code

    xSpeed = Form1.ranNum.Next(1, 20);
    ySpeed = Form1.trackBarValue; // <- An example of what I was hoping to use in my code.
}

public void moveBall()
{
    ballRec.X += xSpeed;
    ballRec.Y -= ySpeed;
}
```

When I run my code as it is, the `xSpeed` works perfectly (as expected) however the `trackBarValue` from the trackbar is not being recognised.

The current properties of my trackbar include:

- Maximum: 100
- Minimum: 20
- Tick Frequency: 0
- Tab Index: 11
- Value: 20

and it's vertical (not that it matters).

How do I gather the values from the trackbar and use them in this ball class? I've made a smaller program that just displays the values of the trackbar in a label every time you move the trackbar but I cannot seem to apply this knowledge into the program above.

Comment: have you checked out the [MSDN Tracker Bar Class Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also based on what you're expecting..have you at least debugged the code / stepped through it..? looks like you're missing an EventHandler for the actual TrackerBar take a look here as well for a tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/trackbar-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: @DJKRAZE I think it's because once the form gets initialised, it doesn't know which value to use from the trackbar hence it sets it to 0. (or at least that's what I could figure out) but I don't know how to set the default value of the trackbar to 20 for example.

Comment: did you look at the link I posted it shows a visual representation also hard to tell what your Initialize(); looks like or what you are doing without seeing relevant code.. should be on the form load I would think

Comment: @DJKRAZE  Hey, thanks for the comments + links, appreciate it. Would you mind having a look at the proposed solution below? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you're setting the value of ySpeed only when the ball is created, it should work if your ball is fastly disposed, but if you're specting it to change its ySpeed value everytime your TrackBarSpeed scrolls then you're going to have some problems.
The easier way o solve your problem is to instead of using a field for ySpeed you use a getter property like so

```
private int xSpeed;
private int ySpeedMod; // we have the direction variable here -1 or 1 so everytime you want to change the direction you change this variable
private int ySpeed {
    get { return Form.trackBarValue * ySpeedMod; }
}
```

like that everytime you reference you ySpeed it will evaluate the get{} Code so it will bring the last value of Y
this happens because int is an struct(value) and not a class(reference) so after you set its value it'll rely on that value given in the specific time

Comment: Sorry I wrote it in stackoverflow so I did not get the syntatic error, it was edited (return before that Form.trackBarValue;)

Comment: Cheers for the edit, however, now I'm getting: `Error 1 Property or indexer 'Breakout.Ball.ySpeed' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.` :S Sorry haha

Comment: Just get that ySpeed = Form.trackBarValue off your code and it should work

Comment: In my collision statements :\ Here's the whole file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4e6d5a23dd5e71646828 (ps. ignore the `if` statements near towards the end of the file)

Comment: Now I get it, it would not work in either ways because you want to modify the ySpeed, but you also want it to be based on the trackBarValue do like this
`private xSpeed;`
`private ySpeedMod; // 1 or -1`
`private ySpeed { get { return Form.trackBarValue * ySpeedMod; }}` and in every ySpeed *= -1 change to ySpeedMod *=  -1
and remember to delete this line 
` ySpeed = Form1.trackBarValue;`

Comment: I'm getting no syntax errors which is fantastic! However, the ball y location is still not changing, as with my original code xD Can it be down to the track bar properties?

Comment: Have you set the default value for ySpeedMod to 1? if not that is the problem

Comment: Yep, that was the problem! Thanks a lot for your help, you've been very kind :D I appreciate you taking your time to explain what to do in detail! :)